# PDO in PHP : fetch() not working

Tags: php, pdo

Here my code :

```
$sql = "select * from dog";

$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth = $sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

But it displays an error :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean**

Why it doesn't work ?

Thank you.

Comment: Your query failed. You need to figure out why.

Comment: You're overwriting `$sth` with the return value of `$sth->execute()`. Don't do that.

Comment: @rickdenhaan, thank you very much.